# The definition of rational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Very often I find this definition of rational numbers in my textbooks:

> A rational number is a number determined by the ratio of some integer p to some nonzero natural number q.

But numbers $$\frac{-1}{-2};\frac{-2}{-4};...$$ are surely rational. Why the denominator has to be a natural number?

Comment: Normalisation. No deeper reason.

Comment: A better definition os of course: A rational number is an equivalence class of pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z\times (\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})$ under the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim (a',b')\iff ab'=a'b$. For the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ we introduce the notation $\frac ab$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword here is **determined**. If you prefer, replace the definition by

> A rational number is a number that **can be** written as $\frac{p}{q}$, with $p$ an integer and $q$ a positive integer

$\frac{-1}{-2}$ can be written as $\frac{1}{2}$, so it's a rational number

$\frac{3\pi}{2\pi}$ can be written as $\frac{3}{2}$ so it's also a rational number

$5$ can be written as $\frac{10}{2}$ so it's also a rational number

But

$\sqrt{2}$ can't be written as a number of the form $\frac{p}{q}$, so it's not a rational number .

Comment: You may want to replace "non-negative" with "positive", since $q$ is at the denominator.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva : ooops ;)